# How to use default action in form_tag for Rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

We need to use `form_tag` in the view for action `new` for `checkouts` controller. Here is the view code:

```
<%= form_tag create_checkout_path, :method => :put do %>
<table class="table table-striped">
  <tr>
     <th></th>
     <th><%= t('Stock#') %></th>
     <th><%= t('Name') %></th>
     <th><%= t('Item Spec') %></th>
     <th><%= t('Stock Qty') %></th>
     <th><%= t('Out Qty') %></th>
  </tr>

<% @item_in_stock.each do |i| %>
  
      <tr>
        <td><%= check_box_tag 'ids[]', i.id %></td>
        <td><%= i.name %></td>
        <td><%= i.item_spec %></td>
        <td><%= i.stock_qty %><%= i.unit %></td>
        <td><%= text_field_tag 'out_qtys[]', '', placeholder: t('Enter checkout qty'), size: '10' %></td>                   
      </tr>
    
<% end %>
```

Here it is in routes.rb:

```
resources :checkouts
```

The view code above returns the error saying that there is no `create_checkout_path` defined. We know how to define a custom action for form_tag. But can we use RAILS default routes in form_tag? We would like to use Rails default action instead of defining our own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
<%= form_tag create_checkout_path, :method => :put do %>
```

to

```
<%= form_tag checkouts_path, :method => :post do %>
```

Comment: Very interesting and will test it. What is the real difference between post and put for broswer behavior? In doc for form_tag, it says "If “patch”, “put”, “delete”, or another verb is used, a hidden input with name _method is added to simulate the verb over post."

Comment: The following rspec case seems not like this change and return false (used to be custom action new_checkout/new_checkout_result): get 'new', {:use_route => :requisition_checkoutx, :item_id => @qi.id}
        response.should be_success

Comment: Run `rake routes` in the terminal to see all the path names along with their type, in this case `create` uses `post`.  And its path is `checkouts_path`

Comment: Yes, there is one:   checkouts GET    /checkouts(.:format)                     requisition_checkoutx/checkouts#index
           POST   /checkouts(.:format)                     requisition_checkoutx/checkouts#create